# Consistent philosophy in the Shulchan Aruch

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, shulchan-aruch

If the Shulchan Aruch primarily rules based on a majority based on the Rif, Rambam and the Rosh, who each (I'm assuming) are usually philosophically internally consistent, then wouldn't the Shulchan Aruch be philosophically internally inconsistent?

Comment: "primarily" "usually" All that could get you is that the ShA is _generally_ consistent.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the Shulchan Aruch is "internally consistent" with regards to ruling like the majority of the three works?

Comment: @DoubleAA Why is it ok for the ShA to be generally consistent? If all the works he is basing his on are internally philosophically consistent, why would the ShA be comfortable with self contradiction?

Comment: @SophArch I didn't say that was ok, and the OP didn't assume the works it is based on are fully internally philosophically consistent. (In any event if the Shulchan Arukh was just meant as cliff notes for the Beit Yosef and he intended you to just use it as a study aid, then bringing contradictory opinions in some places wouldn't be surprising since you are expected to go back and know the Sugya and make a decision.)

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm asking because the Bes Yosef probably would tackle the issue you'd find. Would be a fascinating exercise.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Examples of what?

Comment: @mevaqesh I rolled back your edits, I am really just asking about philosophical consistency and halacha theory

Comment: This is not a question about Jewish philosophy, but about jurisprudence. The hashkafa tag is inappropriate.

Comment: What do you mean by "philosophically," the shulchan aruch is a book of law not ideas?

Comment: @mevaqesh Wouldn't you agree that Jewish law (and other legal systems less so) incorporate a lot of philosophy? Halacha discusses things like how much different kinds of life is worth, how much money is enough for charity, and what the general purpose of metal is. If any Rabbi has a comprehensive and consistent world view (as can be argued the Rambam does) then they cannot say that metal can accept impurity after its cooling in water and then mention another law emphasizing that metal is fine to use for religious objects because metal does not imply weaponry. Jewish law is a balance of values.

Comment: @SophArch Philosophy may sometimes affect Jewish law, but we still have two tags; one for philosophy and one for halakha. The two are two different things even if the former may occasionally affect the latter. BTW if you are the OP, asks the mods to help you merge your account. | If you are the OP, are you only asking about those few halakhot that stem from some philosophical position?

Comment: @mevaqesh I am not the OP. I have just had this same question in the back of my mind. I assume the question is about the implications of being philosophically inconsistent with regard to psak and how that is either not so, or somehow not an issue.

Comment: Can we pretend @sopharch is the OP?

Comment: This is just my guess, but I think all the apparent exceptions to the Shulchan Arukh's rule are really cases where he counted opinions on related topics. In other words, we got theoretical consistency at the expense of the rule's application quite often being far less than obvious. And, at the "expense" of the machaber making a large contribution, in that it would be his call as to whether two machloqesin are related or not.

Comment: Theoretical consistency includes more than philosophy. It could also include things like rules about how rules should be decided, etc... In any case, I though the gemara declaring that anyone who follows the chumeros of both Beis Shammai and Beis Hillel is a chamor was making the point that chumerah without caring about building a consistent spiritual picture is meaningless.

Comment: @MichaBerger Can you please expand on both your comments?

Comment: @wizlog: Since I know what I am trying to say, I cannot figure out what it is I said too quickly and requires more explanation. Could you please provide a specific question? I am just saying that (1) the SA violates his rule more frequently than you'd expect, and (2) it makes sense to assume his rulings are indeed consistent, since the gemara ridicules even chumerah shoppers who are inconsistent about it. We can satisfy both criteria by suggesting that the mechaver is indeed following the majority -- but includes related disputes in the "vote" so that the result is consistent.

Comment: Consistent -- on hashkafic as well as legal reasoning levels. But that requires the mechaber decide what is a related machloqes and what isn't. So, this theory gives the mechaber more say in the result.

Comment: Can you clarify if by "philosophically consistent" you mean always adhering to the same philosophy of legal interpretation, or you mean not contradicting itself on philosophical issues.

Comment: It's not really related exactly, but note that there are occasions where the RamBam "held" like the Jerusalem Talmud and not the Babylonian Talmud for reasons that are not initially/inherently obvious (I'm no expert though, so take this comment with a grain of salt).

Answer (score 2):

No. The philosophy is that majority rules; in that philosophy it is generally consistent.

You could ask the same question about any multi-member court or a legislature. Is it philosophically inconsistent because the majority which rules consists of different individuals each time there is a vote? No, because the philosophy that matters is not the philosophy of each individual, who is not himself the court or legislature anymore than the mailman or janitor is. The relevant philosophy is that of the court itself, which is nothing except the procedures that govern it.

Comment: Does this work out statistically? If we assume that each of the three  are always philosophically consistent then there can never be a philosophical inconsistency in a work that always chooses the majority position. If the Shulchan Aruch endorses philosophy A that means that (at least) 2/3 held of philosophy A. For the Shulchan Aruch to be philosophically inconsistent it would have to reject philosophy A somewhere else, which means that 2/3 had to reject philosophy A elsewhere, so at least 1/3 dchange. Thus, if all 3 are philosophically consistent, the Shulchan Aruch would have to be as well.

Comment: This is not to say that the Shulchan Aruch has no exceptions where it does not follow the majority, and that the Rif, Rambam, and Rosh have no exceptions where they philosophically contradict themselves. But to whatever extent those two rules are followed, the result will also be consistent.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. My point is that each individual's philosophy is irrelevant to the philosophy of the SA as a whole, which is simply that majority should rule.

Comment: It is true that the Shulchan Aruch does not have an independent philosophy (aside from "follow the majority") but my point is that it will be statistically impossible for two places in the Shulchan Aruch to be philosophically inconsistent, because in order for there to be an inconsistency while still following the majority in both places, one of the three sources must be inconsistent. If we are operating under the premise that the three sources are always self-consistent then the Shulchan Aruch will also be. Not for a philosophical reason, but because it's mathematically impossible not to be.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are debating the question, not the answer. I understand the question to be asking as follows. Assume A's philosophy of legal interpretation is Intentionalism, B's is Textualism, and C's is Something Else. If the SA follows AB on one occasion, that ruling is unjustified according to Something Else. When he follows AC, it is unjustified according to Textualism, and when he follows BC it is unjustified according to Intentionalism. It follows that the SA is not internally consistent with any individual's interpretive philosophy, because he'll ignore any. Hence my answer.

Comment: Ah, you are interpreting the question as asking only about an overall philosophy of legal interpretation. In that case you are correct. I had thought the question was about whether there could be a philosophical contradiction on a specific issue, hence my argument that that would be impossible. I already posted my argument separately as an answer; I guess the questioner will have to clarify what he was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let us set up the following steps:

1. The Shulchan Aruch always follows the majority of Rif, Rambam, and Rosh.
2. Each of the three (Rif, Rambam, and Rosh) are philosophically consistent.
3. If none of the three ever changed position on a philosophical matter, then the majority view on the philosophical matter can never have changed either.
4. If the Shulchan Aruch always follows the majority and the majority can never change, ergo the Shulchan Aruch can never change.

Thus, assuming the premises to be true, it should be mathematically impossible for the Shulchan Aruch to be philosophically inconsistent. Any philosophical inconsistencies that do exist would have to be exceptions to one of the premises – either one of the three sources was inconsistent, or the Shulchan Aruch did not follow the majority in (at least one) of the cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, the premises are not always true...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Hence my last sentence.

Comment: it wasn't a critique, it was an expression of agreement ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and assumptions correctly, I think the answer is no. I think this is what you mean: two different halakhot can depend on the same underlying issue. For example, Rabbi Yehudah and Rabbi Shimon disagree regarding muktze in many cases. Let's say two of those cases are Case A and Case B. So if Posek X rules Case A is not muktze it must be because he holds like Rabbi Shimon and therefore should hold Case B is also not muktze.

Based on your premises, there should be no case where the Shulchan Aruch is internally inconsistent because if Halakhah A really implies Halakhah B, there should be the same majority for both halakhot. Going back to our example above, if The Rosh and Rambam both rule Case A is not muktze and the Rif holds it is muktze, then there should be the same 2-1 split in Case B and the Shulchan Aruch would be consistent. On the other hand, if the Rambam holds C and D, the Rif holds C and -D, and the Rosh holds -C and -D, then halakhot C and D must not actually depend on each other (according to your premises) and there would be no inconsistency for the SA to rule C and -D.

I can't think of a scenario where you'd have consistency among the 3 sources but inconsistency in the SA. Can you construct an example?

Anyway, even if there were such a configuration of rulings, I don't think it would necessarily be "inconsistent." The SA sometimes concludes that as a practical matter we should be machmir on a safek, which can sometimes imply chumrot in both directions. For example, I don't think it would be "inconsistent" to say that since we don't know the exact temperature of yad soledet bo we hold it's a lower number when it comes to the isur to heat food on shabat but that it's a higher number when it comes to returning liquids to the fire.

Separately, as many other responses point out, OP's premises are flawed and/or vague. The Mechaber was not a robot and did not resolve all issues on a "best of three" basis. Furthermore, there are many (apparent) contradictions in the Rosh, Rambam, and Rif. But I do think as you've presented it it's an interesting logic puzzle.