# Number of times Rosh, Rif, Rambam are quoted in Shulchan Aruch

Tags: halacha, rambam, shulchan-aruch, rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi

It is known that the author of the Beis Yosef and Shulchan Aruch based his codes on the rulings of the Rosh, Rif and Rambam, and ruled according to the majority of the three. I was wondering to what extent these halachic decisors were quoted in a balanced way in the Shulchan Aruch.

Do we know how many times the Rosh, Rif and Rambam are quoted in Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: Perhaps related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85871/13438

Comment: Do you mean named? Or does this include formulations lifted from their works? Or just general paskin like them?

Comment: I also was unsure your intent

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant how many times they are named

Answer (score 3):

R Haim Jachter answers this question in his book [Bridging Traditions: Demystifying Differences Between Sephardic and Ashkenazic Jews](https://korenpub.com/products/bridging-traditions), on p. 281, footnote 1

> The Rambam is cited by the Shulhan Aruch no less than 10,319 times!
> The next most quoted Rishonim are the Rosh at 8,075 times and the Rif,
> at 3,715 times.

I have to admit I was surprised at the proportions, I didn't realize the Rambam was so preeminent.

Comment: If this means "named" the Rambam is usually named only as a bonus outlier opinion, so your surprise is misplaced

Comment: @DoubleAA you say a chiddush